# How to group table SQL ORACLE table with specific rows also present

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, rollup

I have table like this:

```
Area | Client | Month
a    | A      | 1
a    | B      | 1
b    | C      | 1
a    | A      | 2
b    | B      | 2
```

How can I group and rollup this table, to achieve results like below:

```
Area | Client | Month | Count
a    | A      | 1     | 1
a    | B      | 1     | 1
a    |        | 1     | 2
b    | C      | 1     | 1
b    |        | 1     | 1
     |        | 1     | 3
a    | A      | 2     | 1
a    | B      | 2     | 1
a    |        | 2     | 2
     |        | 2     | 2
     |        |       | 5
```

I would like to count clients by area and months, but to also list client column. I'm having hard time using "group by" with client column present.
I would also like to "order by" month, but with summaries properly ordered too.

Comment: Why are you including the count of clients in the month column? That doesn’t make much sense. Do you absolutely need the total rows? If not, you could use an analytic function to add the relevant counts as columns against each row.

Comment: Thanks, my bad, count should be as another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle already has [rollup and cube grouping functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) for such kind of queries, Use :

```
select area, client , month, sum(month) count
  from mytable
 group by rollup(area, client,month) 
 order by area, client;
```

or, this will produce subtotals of subtotals :

```
select area, client , month, sum(month) count
  from mytable
 group by cube(area, client,month) 
 order by area, client, month;
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [`grouping sets`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E49933_01/server.770/es_eql/src/reql_aggregation_grouping_sets.html) to `cube` or `rollup`, because it is more flexible.

However, the key to using them is that you need an aggregation.  So, I think you want a *fourth* column:

```
select area, client, month, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by grouping sets ( (area, client, month), (area, month), (month));
```

Comment: I think the grouping sets should be `( (area, client, month), (area, month), (month), () )` in order to achieve the OP’s results.